# How to set params in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I config `react-router` like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="product">
        <Route path="list" component={ProductListPage}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="priceReview">
        <IndexRoute component={PriceReviewPage}/>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

`App` Container like this:

```
<div>
    <SideBar curId="index" />

    <div className="layout-content">
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
</div>
```

`SideBar` like this

```
const data: Item[] = [
    { id: "index", desc: "Home", href: "/" },
    { id: "product-manage", desc: "product manager", href: "/product" },
];
export const SideBar = ({ curId }) => (
    <div className="sidebar-nav"><h1 />
        <ul>
            {
                data.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id} className={curId === item.id ? "active" : ""}>
                        {
                            item.isOld === true ?
                                <a href={item.href}><i className="fa fa-home"/><span
                                    className="hidden-tablet">{item.desc}</span></a>
                                :
                                <Link to={item.href}><i className="fa fa-home"/><span
                                    className="hidden-tablet">{item.desc}</span></Link>
                        }
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

What I want to do set `active` className when click the `Link` by this:

```
 <li key={item.id} className={curId === item.id ? "active" : ""}>
```

so I have to set `curId`, but how can I set the `curId`?

Comment: I think you have to explain your problem a bit better. What is `curId`? How does it relate to your router? Explain what you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried using `props` and check the content of these props in the SideBar component?

Comment: If a class on the `<a>` were sufficient you could probably do what you want with the `activeClassName` prop of `<Link>`, but if you need it on the `<li>` it looks like maybe you can accomplish it with [`context.router.isActive()`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/af586416ec02a64a4e70470893e431c580f3ab5d/docs/API.md#isactivepathorloc-indexonly).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use inside your < li >, the < Link /> component from react-router in which you can pass custom styles in the activeClassName props, along with the "classnames" library: https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

Example :

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
render(){ //in your render

  return (

   <div className="sidebar-nav"><h1 />
    <ul>
        {
            data.map((item) => (
                <li key={item.id}>
                  <Link to={item.href} activeClassName={classNames({"active": this.props.curId === item.id})}><i className="fa fa-home"/><span
                            className="hidden-tablet">{item.desc}</span></Link>
                </li>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
   </div>
  );
}
```